# QGIS Plugin folder names mixup

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, github

I've created a python plugin for QGIS. Before I upload it to the QGIS plugins repository, I was doing some testing to make sure it works. In Github, I forked the [master repository](https://github.com/Key-Log-Economics/eco-valuator) and created a working branch. My development version in QGIS has been this branch I created. The plugin works, exists in my QGIS plugins folder, and is called "eco-valuator-CreateAndExportPrintLayout", as this is the name of the GitHub branch I was working in :
[image]

I merged my development branch with the master branch (link above). Now if I download this repository from the master branch, the folder is called "eco-valuator-master". If I put this folder in with the rest of my plugin folders, QGIS doesn't like it. The plugin is listed as "Installed" if I go to "Manage/Install Plugins" but doesn't show in the processing toolbar (where this plugin should be) The photo below shows the one in question, highlighted:
[image]

Lastly, if I manually change the name of the folder from "eco-valuator-master" to "eco-valuator-CreateAndExportPrintLayout", the plugin works. So obviously the issue is with the folder name.

However, I can't find any file within that folder that contains the folder's name, so why is this affecting the way the plugin works in QGIS?

When looking at the [config file](https://github.com/Key-Log-Economics/eco-valuator/blob/master/pb_tool.cfg), it lists the name of the folder will be "ecosystem_service_valuator". Does this impact what is happening? Maybe after I upload the plugin to the QGIS plugins repository, this will be a non-issue?

Comment: I can't answer too much. I didn't try test. FYI, your config file can be safely removed if you don't use `pb_tool`.I python plugin can be 3 files, the init file, metadata.txt and the your plugin.py. I personnaly always use the same folder name, the main plugin name, I have some imports doing `from MyPlugin import foo` so I can't change the plugin folder name!

Comment: Thanks @etrimaille. After uploading the plugin to the QGIS plugins repository, in the end the folder names were not a problem and the issue solved itself.

Comment: I think you should add yu comment as an answer @etrimaille

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After uploading the plugin to the QGIS repository, in the end the folder names were not a problem and the issue solved itself.